# chrome Per-plugin content settings not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Following this guide

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:contentsettings

I'm tryng to list all plugin settings.

Even if I downloaded all the files mentioned the extension does not work.

Errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at array_data_model.js:30
    at Object.define (cr.js:264)
    at array_data_model.js:9
(anonymous) @ array_data_model.js:30
define @ cr.js:264
(anonymous) @ array_data_model.js:9
cr.js:264 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'define' of undefined
    at list_item.js:13
    at Object.define (cr.js:264)
    at list_item.js:5
(anonymous) @ list_item.js:13
define @ cr.js:264
(anonymous) @ list_item.js:5
cr.js:264 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at list_selection_model.js:24
    at Object.define (cr.js:264)
    at list_selection_model.js:5
(anonymous) @ list_selection_model.js:24
define @ cr.js:264
(anonymous) @ list_selection_model.js:5
cr.js:264 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at list_single_selection_model.js:23
    at Object.define (cr.js:264)
    at list_single_selection_model.js:5
(anonymous) @ list_single_selection_model.js:23
define @ cr.js:264
(anonymous) @ list_single_selection_model.js:5
cr.js:264 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ListSelectionModel' of undefined
    at list.js:15
    at Object.define (cr.js:264)
    at list.js:14
(anonymous) @ list.js:15
define @ cr.js:264
(anonymous) @ list.js:14
cr.js:264 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'List' of undefined
    at deletable_item_list.js:6
    at Object.define (cr.js:264)
    at deletable_item_list.js:5
(anonymous) @ deletable_item_list.js:6
define @ cr.js:264
(anonymous) @ deletable_item_list.js:5
cr.js:264 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at inline_editable_list.js:31
    at Object.define (cr.js:264)
    at inline_editable_list.js:5
(anonymous) @ inline_editable_list.js:31
define @ cr.js:264
(anonymous) @ inline_editable_list.js:5
cr.js:264 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'List' of undefined
    at plugin_list.js:11
    at Object.define (cr.js:264)
    at plugin_list.js:10
(anonymous) @ plugin_list.js:11
define @ cr.js:264
(anonymous) @ plugin_list.js:10
cr.js:264 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at plugin_settings.js:30
    at Object.define (cr.js:264)
    at plugin_settings.js:10
(anonymous) @ plugin_settings.js:30
define @ cr.js:264
(anonymous) @ plugin_settings.js:10
cr.js:264 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ArrayDataModel' of undefined
    at rule_list.js:12
    at Object.define (cr.js:264)
    at rule_list.js:9
(anonymous) @ rule_list.js:12
define @ cr.js:264
(anonymous) @ rule_list.js:9
options.html:1 Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read property 'decorate' of undefined
    at chrome-extension://ihlpefadmkecbadnnnhnekfjlcpgkkmh/js/main.js:18:34
```

What did I miss?

The extension is loaded, in developer mode, correctly. However, when I click on the options item the errors I have listed are shown.

Comment: To download the extension you need to click the title which [points to a zip file](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/extensions/plugin_settings.zip).

Comment: The content of downloaded folder is the same that I have. At the same time not working. Same error.

Comment: Then it's a bug in the official extension, which you can report on https://crbug.com.